# JSON.Net cannot deserialize json array in custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

I've run into a confusing problem that i cannot seem to solve.

I'm using Json.Net and i've written a custom Json converter to handle a special case in my application.
The issue i've run into is in the deserialize or `ReadJson` method which is throwing an error when it tires to convert a JSON array into an array of strings:

[image]

The exact text of the error is: `Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path 'RootPages', line 1, position 13.`

As you can see from the inspector, the JProperty it is trying to deserialize (RootPages) has been parsed correctly and is valid JSON.
[image]

So i'm not entirely sure what is going on here, any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated..

If relevant, the original JSON string is as follows:

```
{
  "RootPages": [
    "TestItem1",
    "TestItem2"
  ],
  "Name": "root"
}
```

EDIT-CODE:

ReadJson Method:

```
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if (PartialChildPageSerialization) {
            var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
            var properties = jsonObject.Properties().ToList();

            foreach (var property in objectType.GetProperties()) {
                var type = property.PropertyType;
                object value = null;

                if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ChildPageCollection<>)) {
                    var collection = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    var deserializedValue = properties.First(p => p.Name == property.Name).ToObject<string[]>();
                    type.GetMethod("PolulateFromSerializer").Invoke(collection, new object[] {deserializedValue});
                    value = collection;
                }
                else {
                    value = properties.First(p => p.Name == property.Name).ToObject(type);
                }

                property.SetValue(existingValue, value);
            }

            return existingValue;
        }

        return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
    }
```

Snippet of the interesting part of ChildPageCollection:

```
public class ChildPageCollection<T> : IList<T> where T : DataPage
{
    public string[] GetNames() => _internalNameList.ToArray();

    internal void PolulateFromSerializer(string[] names) {
        this.Clear();
        _internalNameList.AddRange(names);
        _hasFullList = false;
    }

    private void CheckFullList() {
        if(!_hasFullList)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Collection has not been fully loaded, and full list is not avialable.");
    }

    private readonly List<T> _internalList = new List<T>();
    private readonly List<string> _internalNameList = new List<string>();
    private bool _hasFullList = true;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Sure, i thought that may be an issue, but i figured i'd port it first and see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect this is because the first property is an object with a property called 'RootPages' which is a string[].

Unfortunately from the looks of your screenshots you are trying to turn an object into a string array.

This should work in the example you've given:

```
properties.First(p => p.Name == property.Name).Select(o => o.Children().Values<string>()).First().ToArray();
```

In place of:

```
properties.First(p => p.Name == property.Name).ToObject<string[]>();
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that did the trick. Your answer did indeed work, however i did also notice after reading your explanation all i had to add was a `.Value` before the `.ToObject` and the library was able to work out that conversion for me